# How to send a POST request using request module in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, curl, post, request

I have to send the following POST request using Node JS.

```
POST /login.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 20.20.2.11
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://20.20.2.11/login.html
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 133

buttonClicked=4&err_flag=0&err_msg=&info_flag=0&info_msg=&redirect_url=&network_name=Guest+Network&username=f2015764&password=p4asword
```

But the following Node JS code does not work

```
var request = require('request'); 

request.post({
  headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  url:     'https://20.20.2.11/login.html',
  body:    'buttonClicked=4&username=f2015764&password=haXor21*'
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to send a url query inside your body. Try changing the body. `body: { 'buttonClicked': 4, 'username': 'f2015764', 'password': 'haXor21*'}`

Comment: okay, so I forgot add `method:POST` and due to the insecure connection I had to add `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";` and the top of my code.
Thanks anyways :)